# Iterate through records and replace attributes in multiple records based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following data which I'm trying to clean.

| VEHICLE | FROM | TO | START | replacement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | B | A |  |
| 2 | B | C | A |  |
| 2 | C | D | A |  |
| 2 | D | **E** | A |  |
| 2 | **E** | F | E | 123 |
| 2 | G | H | E | 123 |
| 2 | I | J | E | 123 |
| 2 | W | X | W |  |
| 2 | X | Y | W |  |
| 2 | Y | Z | W |  |
| 3 | Q1 | Q2 | W |  |
| 3 | Q2 | Q3 | W |  |

My goal is, that whenever there are records with the same vehicle and replacement is not NULL and there is a record where replacement is NULL (for the same vehicle) and the **TO** attribute of the record with replacement NULL equals the **FROM** attribute of the record with replacement not NULL, it should replace the **START** attribute in all records where the replacement IS NOT NULL and same vehicle with the **START** attribute of the on match above.

So the result should look like the following:

| VEHICLE | FROM | TO | START | replacement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | B | A |  |
| 2 | B | C | A |  |
| 2 | C | D | A |  |
| 2 | D | E | A |  |
| 2 | E | F | **A** | 123 |
| 2 | G | H | **A** | 123 |
| 2 | I | J | **A** | 123 |
| 2 | W | X | W |  |
| 2 | X | Y | W |  |
| 2 | Y | Z | W |  |
| 3 | Q1 | Q2 | W |  |
| 3 | Q2 | Q3 | W |  |

Notice, that there are other entries with vehicle = 2 which stay unaffected (W-Z)

I already tried a lot in pure SQL with lead and lag, so I could replace the first row (FROM E to F) but I wasn't able to replace all necessary rows, because there was no criteria for me to use.
So I guess there's no way around using PL/SQL and do it procedural, but I don't know exactly how to solve that. I can do some PL/SQL, but I'm no expert in it.

Here's the set of the table above to use. I would appreciate any help very much.

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'A' "FROM", 'B' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'B' "FROM", 'C' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'C' "FROM", 'D' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'D' "FROM", 'E' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'E' "FROM", 'F' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'G' "FROM", 'H' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'I' "FROM", 'J' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'W' "FROM", 'X' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'X' "FROM", 'Y' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'Y' "FROM", 'Z' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 "vehicle", 'Q1' "FROM", 'Q2' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 "vehicle", 'Q2' "FROM", 'Q3' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match_recognize for that:

Just to make it easier to understand, I've added your required result as `NEW_START` column.

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/PgCeARDJ

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'A' "FROM", 'B' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'B' "FROM", 'C' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'C' "FROM", 'D' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'D' "FROM", 'E' "TO", 'A' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'E' "FROM", 'F' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'G' "FROM", 'H' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'I' "FROM", 'J' "TO", 'E' "START", 123 "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'W' "FROM", 'X' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'X' "FROM", 'Y' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 "vehicle", 'Y' "FROM", 'Z' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 "vehicle", 'Q1' "FROM", 'Q2' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 "vehicle", 'Q2' "FROM", 'Q3' "TO", 'W' "START", NULL "replacement" FROM dual
)
SELECT 
   "vehicle"
  ,"FROM"
  ,"TO"
  ,"START"
  ,"replacement"
  ,new_start,mno,cls
FROM a
match_recognize(
  partition by "vehicle"
  order by "FROM"
  MEASURES  
     A."START" as NEW_START
    ,MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
    ,CLASSIFIER() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  pattern (A (B C*)?)
  DEFINE
    B as (B."FROM" = prev(B."TO") and B."replacement" is not null and prev(B."replacement") is null),
    C as (C."replacement" is not null)
)
order by 1,2
;
```

[image]

Comment: This is so awesome! You don't know how much you made my day. Thank you very much.